# Selection.containsNode() returning true even when Node is not contained

Tags: dom, selection

[image]

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection/containsNode

> Parameters
>
> node
> The node that is being looked for in the selection. partialContainment Optional
> When true, containsNode() returns true when a part of the node is part of the selection. When false, containsNode() only returns true
> when the entire node is part of the selection. If not specified, the
> default value false is used.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a workaround (in typescript)

```
function getRangePartiallySelectedNodes(
  selection: Selection,
  parent: Node
): Node[] {
  return [
    // containsNode doesn't work as expected, always gives partial nodes
    ...(selection.containsNode(parent, true) ? [parent] : []),
    ...(parent.hasChildNodes()
      ? Array.from(parent.childNodes)
          .map((node) => getRangePartiallySelectedNodes(selection, node))
          .flat()
      : []),
  ];
}

function isAncestor(node: Node, possibleAncestor: Node): boolean {
  if (!node || !node.parentNode) return false;
  return (
    node.parentNode.isSameNode(possibleAncestor) ||
    isAncestor(node.parentNode, possibleAncestor)
  );
}

export function selectionContainsNodes(
  sel: Selection,
  // limitation: the selection must be within the elementEditing node
  elementEditing: HTMLElement
): boolean {
  if (sel.isCollapsed) return false;
  const nodes = getRangePartiallySelectedNodes(sel, elementEditing);
  // sel.anchorNode and sel.focusNode may be parents of the actual selection start instead of the selection themselves
  return nodes.some(
    (node) =>
      !isAncestor(sel.anchorNode, node) &&
      !node.isSameNode(sel.anchorNode) &&
      !isAncestor(sel.focusNode, node) &&
      !node.isSameNode(sel.focusNode)
  );
```

Comment: Is this a bug?  I have been fighting this for two days now... it seems like Selection.containsNode is very unreliable. I created a fiddle to test a case like you found and inexplicably containsNode returned `false` for *EVERY* node in the selection. I am about to tear my hair out here.

Comment: Also, I'm not too familiar with typescript so I'm not sure what the workaround is supposed to be doing.